# Error maven appassembler generate-daemons for solaris-sparc-64

Tags: java, maven, appassembler

I am using appassembler to generate the shell script for solaris-sparc-64 but somehow it is failing. It is giving following warning messges.

```
[WARNING] Lib file for wrapper-windows-x86-32 not found in map.
[WARNING] Lib file for solaris-sparc-32-exec not found in map.
[WARNING] Lib file for solaris-sparc-64-exec not found in map.
[WARNING] Exec file for wrapper-windows-x86-32 not found in map.
[WARNING] Exec file for solaris-sparc-32-exec not found in map.
[WARNING] Exec file for solaris-sparc-64-exec not found in map.
```

and it does not create any script file for solaris. Can anyone please help me?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-daemons</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <daemons>
                    <daemon>
                        <id>app</id>
                        <mainClass>com.app.MainApp</mainClass>
                        <jvmSettings>
                            <extraArguments>
                                <extraArgument>-DENVIRONMENT=00</extraArgument>
                            </extraArguments>
                        </jvmSettings>
                        <platforms>
                            <platform>jsw</platform>
                        </platforms>
                        <generatorConfigurations>
                            <generatorConfiguration>
                                <generator>jsw</generator>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>linux-x86-32</include>
                                    <include>wrapper-windows-x86-32</include>
                                    <include>solaris-sparc-32-exec</include>
                                    <include>solaris-sparc-64-exec</include>
                                </includes>
                            </generatorConfiguration>
                        </generatorConfigurations>
                    </daemon>
                </daemons>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: First you should remove the "-exec" in the include part like solaris-sparc-32-exec, solaris-sparc-64-exec

Comment: Furthermore remove the "wrapper" in front of wrapper-windows-x86-32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to remove the "-exec" parts and the "wrapper-" prefix from the platform includes in your configuration. Furthermore if this information is extracted from the documentation ? If yes than i would appreciate if you file in an [issue into the tracking system](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAPPASM).